# Calculating time lapse between dates vertically in python/pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, timestamp, time-series, pivot

**System:** WIN10

**IDE:** Visual Studio Code

**Language:** Python version 3.7.6

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**User Story:**

I am trying to count lapse time between dates in a data frame conditional on: ‘Name’.  While there are several columns in the data frame I need to keep I am trying to find out how to count time downward in the data frame that is sorted on ‘Name’ and ‘Date’ as new names appear and only between new instances/observations for that person.

Example

```
df.head()
```

[image]

Intended

[image]

In the intended example it shows that for instance Melvin Heard’s (fake names) first training: Level I = 0, while going from Level I to Level II took him in the example 74 days, and so on…

**Steps were taken:**

1. searched StackOverflow for timeseries exaples
2. trying using pivot functions to reverse melt the training levels into the columns and calculate date
3. analyzed number two's output but it is not acceptable for analysis needs
4. I tried using this method but it counts time for the previous employee and doesn't factor that I need this for each individual employee:

   df4['day_diff'] = df4['Date'] \ .diff().dt.days.fillna(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this:

```
# calculate days between 'Event' by employee: 'Time Lapse'
df['Time Lapse'] = d4.groupby(['Name', 'Training Level'])['Date'] \
                            .diff().dt.days.fillna(0)
```

Thanks to anyone who was trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the underlying numpy arrays:

```
d = df['Date'].values  # get numpy arrays
df.loc[1:, 'Lapsed Time'] = d[1:] - d[:-1]  # first day is NaN, because no 0th day.
```

Do this for each group (group by Name, etc.) and collect the results.

Comment: Will this method place the data back into the original dataframe? Here is a method I just tried a second ago but it seems to count time for different people and this is not what I need. 'df4['day_diff'] = df4['Date'] \
.diff().dt.days.fillna(0)'